# Prove that $\int_0^1 |f'(re^{it})| dr<\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U$ be the unit disc and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|<\infty$. Prove that $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ for every $z \in U$ satisfies
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 |f'(re^{it})| dr<\infty
\end{equation} for every $t$. It seems that the solution is to take the derivative term by term and then integrate from $0$ to $1$ directly. Is it really the correct way? Or am I missing something important?

Comment: That is the right  way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that works. What you are essentially using is that $|f'(z)| \le g'(|z|)$ where $g$ is defined in the unit disk as
$$
 g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n| z^n \, .
$$
Then for all $\rho \in (0, 1)$
$$
\int_0^\rho |f'(re^{it})| \, dr \le \int_0^\rho g'(r) \, dr = g(\rho)-g(0) \le \sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n| \, .
$$
It follows that $\int_0^1 |f'(re^{it})| \, dr$ is finite, and in fact bounded above independently of $t$.